# Elasticsearch request how get the top 20 videos between two times

Tags: json, elasticsearch, facet

I need to find the 20 most views videos between two times, i did this:

```
    $Param['body']='
 {
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "WhatIwant" : {
            "range" : {
                "key_field" : "time",
                "value_field" : "video_id",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "from" :1399236597 , "to" : 1400331247 }

                ]
            }

        }

    }
}';
```

I get a result where i can see some params, but i don't have the entire list look:

```
    [facets] => Array
        (
            [WhatIwant] => Array
                (
                    [_type] => range
                    [ranges] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [from] => 1400331247
                                    [count] => 4585
                                    [min] => -1
                                    [max] => 3584
                                    [total_count] => 4585
                                    [total] => 12884198
                                    [mean] => 2810.0758996728
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want  something like this if it's possible :

```
     [facets] => Array
        (
            [WhatIwant] => Array
                (
                    [_type] => range
                    [ranges] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [time] => 1400331247
                                    [video_id] => 4585

                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [time] => 1400331248
                                    [video_id] => 4582

                                )
                            [2] =>Array()
                            .....
                            ....
                             [19]
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `term` facet, grouped by `video_id` with applied range filter

Comment: i did this but it's not want i want...   {
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
  "whatiwant" : {
   "terms" : {
    "field" : "video_id"
      },
   "range" : {
     "key_field" : "time",
     "ranges" : [{"from": 1399236597 , "to" : 1400331247}]
       }
    }
  
    }
}

Comment: you need something like: 
{ "query" : { "match_all" : {} }, "facets" : { "whatiwant" : { "terms" : { "field" : "video_id" }, facet_filter: { "range" : {"from": 1399236597 , "to" : 1400331247}}}}

Comment: I did this and it works thx for your help.
    {
    "facets": {
        "videos": {
          "terms": {"field": "video_id", "size": "21"},
           "facet_filter": {
           "range": {
            "time": {"from" :"'.$startTime.'", "to": "'.$endTime.'"}
              }
          }
         }
      },
      "query": {"match_all": {}}}
      
      }